# Changing the positive label in sklearn.metrics.precision_score()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have two binary images (black(0) and white(255) one is the ground truth image while the other is the predicted image from the neural network. I used the sklearn.metrics.precision_score() to get the precision between the two images. But by default it takes the black pixels as the 'positive' label. How to change the white pixels as the 'positive' label?

Ex (255 as 1):

precision = true_positive/(true_positive+false_positive)

```
ground_truth = [0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
predicted    = [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0]
```

if 1 is taken as the positive value,

```
 true_positive = 3
 fale_positive = 2
 fale_negative = 3
 true_negative = 2

 precision =3/(3+2)=0.6
```

if 0 is taken as the positive value,

```
 true_positive = 2
 fale_positive = 3
 fale_negative = 2
 true_negative = 3

 precision =2/(2+3)=0.4
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_score

Comment: `1 - ground_truth` assuming you're using numpy arrays?

Comment: yes I'm using numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

First inverted the element of predicted then find precision with ground_truth and predicted_inverted. Hope this may help.

```
map_dict = {0:1,1:0}
predicted_inverted = list(map(lambda x: map_dict[x],predicted))
```